# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource in `meteor`

Tags: meteor

How to solve the **cross-origin request blocked** in meteor after `deploy` the app.Bellow error will came and blank page will showing.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ddp--1816-sampleearth911.meteor.com/sockjs/info?cb=gh4l55k2_s. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: you might get more answers if you give more context of your error

Comment: update the error please verify and suggest me@ imslavko

Comment: is your site https://sampleearth911.meteor.com/? It works without cors warnings for me. You have other errors in the JS console.

Comment: yaa that is my site when open in browser only blank page will came.@ imslavko